# How can I place 8 figures in 3 rows and 3 columns (last row should contain 2 figures) in IEEEtran format?

Tags: tables, floats, ieeetran

I wrote this code :

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{nccmath, amssymb,mathtools}% nccmath had to be loaded before mathtools
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{placeins}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{c c c}
  \includegraphics[width=2in]{1}&
  \includegraphics[width=2in]{2} &
  \includegraphics[width=2in]{3} \\
  \includegraphics[width=2in]{1} &
  \includegraphics[width=2in]{2} &
  \includegraphics[width=2in]{3} \\
  \includegraphics[width=2in]{1} &
  \includegraphics[width=2in]{2} &
  \includegraphics[width=2in]{3} \\
  a.~Subcaption A & b.~Subcaption B & c.~Subcaption C
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{A caption}
\end{figure*}
```

I want to add caption to each individual figure. Moreover the general caption of the figure does not comply with IEEEtran format.

Output looks like this:
[image]

**Edit:**

The overall caption should be like the one in the image (in IEEEtran format - the main caption body in italics).

[image]

Comment: Should the 8 graphs be treated as separate subfigures, labeled from from a to h?

Comment: May or may not be. I just want separate caption for each figure apart from a caption for the overall figure.

Comment: Are you quite sure that "Fig. 9. *Power Consumption in ...*" is the default form of figure captions? For sure, if I compile the minimalist document `\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran} \begin{document} \setcounter{figure}{8} \begin{figure} \caption{Power consumption in\dots} \end{figure} \end{document}`, I get "Fig. 9. Power Consumption in ..." -- *without italics*.

Comment: Okay. I'll recheck and let you know if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal,demo]{IEEEtran} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{nccmath, amssymb,mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{placeins}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
\centering
    \subfloat[aaa]{\includegraphics[width=2in]{1}}
    \label{fig:aa}\hfill
    \subfloat[bbb]{\includegraphics[width=2in]{2}}
    \label{fig:bb}\hfill
    \subfloat[ccc]{\includegraphics[width=2in]{3}}
    \label{fig:cc}

    \subfloat[ddd]{\includegraphics[width=2in]{4}}
    \label{fig:dd}\hfill
    \subfloat[eee]{\includegraphics[width=2in]{5}}
    \label{fig:ee}\hfill
    \subfloat[fff]{\includegraphics[width=2in]{6}}
    \label{fig:ff}

    \subfloat[ggg]{\includegraphics[width=2in]{7}}
    \label{fig:gg}\hspace{0.1\textwidth}
    \subfloat[hhh]{\includegraphics[width=2in]{8}}
    \label{fig:hh}
\caption{Overall caption}
\label{fig:images}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, I want it like this indeed except the overall caption. Plz see the edit to the original question.

Comment: If you write `\caption{\textit{Your caption}}` it should be italized. Are you sure captions must be like that though? Asking out of self interest! EDIT: I checked the official guidelines of IEEEtrans and it does not specify that captions must be in cursive. Rather, the examples offered are all in "normal" format

Comment: @Jes - With `\caption{\textit{Your caption}}`, "Your caption" will be italicized, whereas the preceding "Fig. 1:" string will not.

Comment: @Mico - You are right, I did not think about that.